# zod conditional validation base on form field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, zod

I have a `status = 'DRAFT' | 'READY'` enum field in my form, is it possible to change validation in `zod` lib based on value of this field?

```
// validation passed
{
  name: "John",
  surname: null,
  status: "DRAFT"
}

// validation failed
{
  name: "John",
  surname: null,
  status: "READY"
}
```

So esentialy if `status === "READY"` remove `.min(1)` from here

```
const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  surname: z.string().min(1),
  status: z.enum(["READY", "DRAFT"])
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer you came up with using `union`s is possible. An alternative that might yield better types in the future is to take advantage of zod's [`discriminatedUnion`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#discriminated-unions) schema:

```js
// placing shared fields in one place to avoid repetition
const base = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
});

const schema = z.discriminatedUnion(
  'status',
  [
    z.object({
      status: z.literal("DRAFT"),
      surname: z.string(),
    }).merge(base),
    z.object({
      status: z.literal("READY"),
      surname: z.string().min(1),
    }).merge(base),
  ],
);
```

In this case I believe you'll end up with the same inferred types as you would using `union` directly, however, this approach is slightly more resilient to other changes you might want to discriminate between. For example if the `DRAFT` object allowed `surname` to be `optional` then using the discriminated union would me that you could refine to non-optional types if `status` is `"READY"`.

With `union` definition, the type for `surname` in that example would always be `string | undefined` regardless of the value of `status`.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
const schema = z.union([
  z.object({
    name: z.string(),
    surname: z.string(),
    status: z.literal("DRAFT"),
  }),
  z.object({
    name: z.string(),
    surname: z.string().min(1),
    status: z.literal("READY"),
  }),
]);
```